# Generate JsonSchema where properties have more than one type

Tags: java, json, jackson

When producing the schema for a Java type I would like to specify that certain String values (or other types) could be null or "Nullable", for example, if there is a "name" property with this requirement I'd like to see something like this in the output:

```
"name" : {
      "type" : ["string", "null"]
 }
```

Additionally, what if I want to allow a value to be either integer or String? How can Jackson's schema generation be informed about it? I mean something like this:

```
 "id" : {
      "type" : ["string", "integer"]
      "required" : true
    }
```

But so far the things that I've attempted with Jackson are not working. I have the following method that at runtime will create a JsonSchema for the input type:

```
public String getJsonSchema(Class<Message> type) throws IOException{
    ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonSchemaGenerator generator = new JsonSchemaGenerator(m);
    JsonSchema schema = generator.generateSchema(type);
    return m.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(schema);
}
```

Message.java is something like this (I removed the setters to keep the code shorter):

```
public class Message {  
private String name;
private Long id;

@JsonProperty(value = "name", required = false)
@JsonPropertyDescription("User provided name.")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@JsonProperty(value = "id", required = true)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
}
```

The output for the previous bean is this:

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "id" : "urn:jsonschema:spring:integration:quickstart:Message",
  "properties" : {
    "name" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "description" : "User provided name."
    },
    "id" : {
      "type" : "integer",
      "required" : true
    }
  }
}
```

The question is, what annotation or configuration option is required to make "null" one of the possible types for name?

Comment: How can i type be null? isn't it a value?